# How to control other component's css in react?

Tags: css, reactjs

When I focus on the input tag in React, I want to create an animation where the dot at the center under the input tag called `inputBottomEffect` spreads out on oth sides.
I don't know how to touch the css of `inputBottomEffect` when the input tag is in focus...

---

sample code :

```
    <inputWrapper>
        <input type="text" ... />
        <inputBottomDiv></inputBottomDiv>
        <inputBottomEffect></inputBottomEffect> // input's bottom border
    </inputWrapper>
```

---

screenshot :

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UumEB.png)

[spreading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYx3d.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWVk3.png)

Comment: please add code of your elements

Comment: Not sure if I understand it right, but you should be able to use normal css with this, given the inputBottomEffect HTML element has a classname: input:focus ~ .inputBottomEffectClassName {//your styles here }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a state boolean that is going to keep track of whether or not this input is in focus. Then you want to add a css class to the desired attribute only when that state evaluates to true.

Create a state boolean that can keep track of whether this component is in focus:

```
const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
```

In your input field put:

```
<input 
    onFocus={e => focusHandler(true)}
    onBlur={e => focusHandler(false)} 
/>

function focusHandler(isFocused) {
   setIsFocused(isFocused)
}
```

Then create a css class that is only active when that isFocused is true

```
<inputBottomEffect className={isFocused ? "FocusedCssClass" : "UnfocusedCssClass"}
```

Now just put all of your animation CSS in "FocusedCssClass"

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the ~ or the + in css, with the ~ you can select of the target selector after the first selector.

```css
.first_paragraph {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.first_paragraph ~ .next_paragraph {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<p class='first_paragraph'>First</p>
<p class='next_paragraph'>Second</p>
<p>Third</p>
<p class='next_paragraph'>Fourth</p>
```

Or if you need to target 1 selector only then the + sign, like this:

```css
.first_paragraph {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.first_paragraph + .next_paragraph {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<p class='first_paragraph'>First</p>
<p class='next_paragraph'>Second</p>
<p>Third</p>
<p class='next_paragraph'>Fourth</p>
```

Comment: I learned something new about css. Thank you!!